# Hough perfect Line fit and select single perfect line fit image

Tags: python, opencv

This is the image I tried to fit lines into but it detects multiple lines. I tried different approaches but was not able to get results that could best fit a single line on the image.

Edged image after auto canny:

[image: Edged image after auto canny]

Result after `hough`:

[image: Result after hough]

Original image:

[image: Original image]

Comment: try using LineSegmentDetector or ED-Lines. Another approach could be to post process the houghLines by comparing the line pixels by a sobel gradient and only choose the line(s) with the bigges gradient magnitude sum or whatever.

Comment: what are we seeing in that picture, apart from the lines your code drew? anything but a hough transform will probably give better results for less calculation.

Comment: I apply hough transform on image and I just got this result in post processing I filter out noise and use canny to detect edge@ChristophRackwitz

Comment: An idea is 1) Load image, grayscale, Otsu's threshold for a binary image. 2) morph open to remove the small noise particles, then Canny edge detection to search for the two sides of the line. From here you can either detect vertical lines with a vertical kernel + morph operations or use HoughLines for line detection

Comment: @nathancy Morph doesn't fit into the image cause it blurs the actual edges and when we apply canny it also  considers lines from the background.

Comment: @Micka line segment detector or ED is not fit for image cause background is not steady or clear.

Comment: can you show the input that you use for HoughLines Opertaion?

Comment: I meant the input image. Afair HoughLines gets mask input, so how to you extract edges before computing houghLines? Can you show the `edged` image?

Comment: @Micka I added an edged image in question

Comment: What about using LSD / ED on the edged image and only keep line segments of a minimum length? You could even use LSD / ED on the original image and only keep segments that fall in a mask which is drawn from your hough lines result.

Comment: @Micka If possible can you provide the code? Input to the LSD is a gray image so the edged image is already in gray so LSD = cv2.createLineSegmentDetector(o) giving error in my case so I apply FLD but results are not good.